# Unable to find pdflatex.fmt

Tags: pdftex, installing

I'm trying to get pdflatex working on [AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/) and I've hit a roadblock. I believe I have the basic tex engine running as I'm able to run the command `pdflatex -version` and get the correct information.

However, when I try to compile an actual latex file (`pdflatex sample.tex`) I get the following error:

```
   kpathsea: Running mktexfmt pdflatex.fmt
   mktexfmt: No such file or directory
```

Due to the ephemeral nature of AWS Lambda I created a new `bin/` folder, added it to the `$PATH` and included in it all of the required dependencies as well as rebuild the `ls-R` file at the root of the directory. The `ls-R` file contains the location of `pdflatex.fmt` but my guess is that it's not searching the correct directory for the `ls-R` file. The [`kpathsea`](http://tug.org/texinfohtml/kpathsea.html#ls_002dR) documentation states you can set the default installation location in `$TEXMF` but that doesn't seem to have worked.

```
$ echo $TEXMF
/var/task/bin # the created bin directory
```

Any ideas on how to continue debugging this installation? Or if there's a better approach at this.

Comment: Welcome! So does `kpswhich pdflatex.fmt` return nothing? What have you set `TEXMF` to? Do you mean that you have `ls-R`, `bin/`? Do you not have `texmf.cnf` somewhere? I guess ... how familiar are you with TeX Live in other contexts?

Comment: @cfr thanks for the help! I do not have the command `kpswhich` (I installed the texlive-scheme-basic if that changes anything). I don't have much familiarity with TeX Live in general other than the reading that I've been doing in the past couple of days (if you have any useful links I appreciate it). I realized that I hadn't modified the contents of `texmf.cnf` to match the Lambda environment but that didn't change anything. I've updated the original question with the value of `$TEXMF`. I'm not sure I get your question about `ls-R` and `bin/`.

Comment: I can't imagine the basic schema does not include `kpsewhich`. At least, that's surprising. `kpsewhich`is part of the `kpathsea` TeX Live package. It is part of `collection-basic` and classified as `TLCore`.

Comment: Do you have `mktexfmt`? That looks to be missing too? You seem to be missing essential binaries or they are not found in your PATH.

Comment: It looks like they tried to use `kpswhich`, but that is a typo. It should be `kpsewhich`

Comment: I could fix this issue by unsetting TEXMF in my case ;)

Answer (score 1):

The error is even before finding the `latex.fmt` file.

```
   mktexfmt: No such file or directory
```

Here, the engine is complaining that it cannot find the `mktexfmt` binary. I ran into this issue as well, and after spending some time trying to find the `[xe]latex.fmt` file, I tried to obtain the `mktexfmt` binary.

1. Open up `tlmgr -gui`, and in the "Match" textbox, input `mktexfmt`. This will display one or two packages, named `texlive-scripts`.
2. Select all that you see at the end of this search, and install. I would guess that using the CLI, you could alternatively do `tlmgr install texlive-scripts`.

At the end of this, the LaTeX   engine stopped complaining about not finding `mktexfmt`, so I imagine it is supplied by the `texlive-scripts` package.

Comment: Fixed this on my Arch installation by installing the `texlive-core` package from extra.